# What is Modal's onClose equivalent to Dart/Flutter's Dialog?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to refresh my states upon a dialog close, either by submission or on exit by the user pressing outside of the dialog. How will I capture that? Which is equivalent to JS/React's Modal onClose.

```
  showDialog(
  context: this.context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Add a custom word'),
      content: _renderForm(),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('ADD'),
          onPressed: () => (_textController.text.isNotEmpty) ? _addNewPair() : null,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the `await` keyword before `showDialog` :

```
    yourMethod () async {

    await showDialog(
      context: this.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Add a custom word'),
          content: _renderForm(),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('ADD'),
              onPressed: () => (_textController.text.isNotEmpty) ? _addNewPair() : null,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }

      //here you can continue because your dialog was closed
      print("after my dialog was closed");

      }
```

If you want to close youd dialog just use this :

```
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just double checking though, is this considered as the 'standard' way to handle onClose?

Comment: yes, also check the property 'barrierDismissible' of the showDialog, you can set it to false to avoid the user press outside the dialog

Comment: Depending on what you want, a WillPopScope is also a solution